# MYSQL Slow load and Optimization

Tags: mysql

Have an issue with the MYSQL Server, actually don't know if its the queries or the SQL Config itself, but most of time the queries load fast and properly, but sometimes it just gets stuck loading, or not load and give timeout error.

When Nginx top process is check this is what it shows

```
PID     USER    PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR   S  %CPU  %MEM     TIME+  COMMAND
13876   mysql   20  0   2827864 203292   8752  S   0.0  2.6  479:33.31  mysqld
```

In PHPMyAdmin it shows this advice,

[image]

Don't know how to resolve these issues, any guide to where to check from, or any solution?

UPDATE- slow log info - 1 query causing this issue? any solution?
[image]

Comment: Note the time for MySQL its high, does that affecting anything?

Comment: I understand that you think your mysql is slow, but there is nothing in your question that would give any hint as to what's wrong. The process entry shows 0 CPU utilisation and a minimal memory footprint. Moreover, SO is a programming Q/A site. We gladly help you to optimise an sql query, database or index structures. But if you need help with cofiguring mysql, then the dba sister site of SO is the one that can help you.

Comment: Please post the complete first page of TOP for much useful information.  Time at 479:33:31 indicates mysqld has been online for 479Hours.  Please also post SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; complete first page.  Search for MySQL SLOW QUERY LOG TUTORIAL and get your slow query log functioning.  Welcome to stackoverflow.com.  Once you have the Slow Query Log recording activity, you will be able to share the query that is slow for suggestions on how to improve query completion time.  If you are not familiar with indexes, https://use-the-index-luke.com/  will help you become familiar with the terms/concept.

Comment: @WilsonHauck I have updated the question with the slow log, any useful?

Comment: Please post TEXT results of A) SHOW CREATE TABLE rewarded_details; B) SHOW CREATE TABLE user_details; C) SHOW INDEX FROM rewarded_details; D) SHOW INDEX FROM user_details; and E) EXPLAIN SELECT ....(rest of your query); for someone to provide SLOW QUERY ANALYSIS summary after analyzing these 5 pieces of information. Yes we know it takes time.

Answer (score 0):

As PHPMyAdmin's advices, you have some problems about table indexes. You can find more details about indexes [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_index)

1. You should store your user's UserID (*[Primary Key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unique_key)*) in `rewarded_details` table as *[Foreign Key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key)*.

   The joining table over username will affect the speed of the query execution because of this column is string and have no index.
   So, you should join over the user id. By changing this column, your join query need to be changed according to this column. You will need to add index to this new column (**Foreign Key**).
2. You should add index to **reward_points** column.
3. In your software, you should not create new connection in every query. You should create as little as possible new connection.
4. You can enable query cache.

Edit: Don't forget to backup your data.